# Reclaiming Disk Space

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

According to section 7 of the [original bitcoin spec.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_white_paper#Reclaiming_Disk_Space) by Satoshi:

> Once the latest transaction in a coin is buried under enough blocks,
>   the spent transactions before it can be discarded to save disk space.

In order to get the bitcoin-qt client running, I am currently downloading the ENTIRE block chain from the https://bitcoin.org/bin/blockchain/bootstrap.dat.torrent

Is there a smaller download somewhere? My google skills are failing me, plz help.

Comment: You could use a thin-client like MultiBit which doesn't require the entire blockchain to be downloaded.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Have a look at the question Nate points to, according to the answers given therein the download size would not be reduced, only the storage.